# Friending/Using a class in a different namespace

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, friend

If the class `G` is in the namespace `GSpace` and it needs to be friends with the class `M` in the global namespace what do you have to do?  I thought this would work:

```
/////////////////////M.h//////////////////////
#include "GFile.h"

class M
{
   public:
      friend class GSpace::G; // doesn't work, throws error
}
```

After researching on StackOverflow a bit, I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843743/1797424

```
/////////////////////M.h//////////////////////

namespace GSpace 
{
   class G;
}

class M
{
   public:
      friend class GSpace::G; // works, no error
   private:
      GSpace::G gClassMember; // errors: "M uses undefined class GSpace::G"
};
// Note that G.h includes M.h so I do not include it here, 
// instead I have it included in M.cpp
```

That does work for getting the class friended.  However, it creates an issue when I actually declare a class member using that type, because the class is not defined.  GFile.h

Am I misunderstanding how `#include` and forward declaration behaves, or is it some kind of implementation issue on the side of the compiler (not likely, I'm assuming)?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/l9s72G. What is the error? Does `GFile.h` actually define `GSpace::G`?

Comment: The error is..? I'll bet either that `GFile.h` includes the file containing `class M`, or that you're missing [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) and need them.

Comment: @DarkFalcon The error I'm getting is that G is undefined when I try to create a member of it in class M.  Both files have include guards, and there is no circular dependencies (that I have found).  I'll update my code to include this error.

Comment: @Josh: Making a class a friend doesn't bring its name into the local scope. You still need to qualify it with the namespace.

Comment: @DarkFalcon It is (forgot to put it in the mockup code, was in a bit of a rush when writing it :/ ).  Is there anything else that looks incorrect about this?

Comment: @Josh: The full definition of `G` also needs to be available, as the compiler needs to know its size. You cannot use only a forward declaration as you have it now. (Note, it would help if you can demonstrate with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Because your member is not a pointer or reference, the compiler needs to know the size of `G`. You can't use a forward declaration.
- As noted in the comment, you need to qualify `G` with the namespace.

Here is code which compiles for me:

```
namespace GSpace
{
   class G
   {
   };
}

class M
{
   public:
      friend class GSpace::G;
   private:
      GSpace::G gClassMember;
};

int main() {return 0;}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you.  Would this be the same situation if it was a parameter for a method?  Does the compiler need to know the size of those ahead of time as well? Can it figure out how much stack allocation a parameter needs at runtime?

Comment: A parameter to a method can be forward-declared, but you couldn't call that method until the parameter type is declared. This is compile-time only. C++ has no built-in reflection or metadata to allow runtime determination of a method parameter sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
namespace GSpace
{
   class G;
}

class M
{
   public:
      friend class GSpace::G; 
}

namespace GSpace
{
   class G { /* definition of the class */ };
}
```